# Obtener la fecha real de creación de un registro

Tags: sql, date, registro

En microsoft Navision Tengo una tabla  ("T03") que guarda la fecha de creación de registros por intervalos por ejemplo
[image: Tabla1]

y una tabla de hechos ("T01") donde se registran documentos contables
[image: Tabla 2]

Quiero obtener la fecha real de creación del documento en base a la tabla "T03" por ejemplo el documento 32446680 tiene fecha 16/06/2022 siendo la fecha real de registro 26/06/2022
[image: Resultado Esperado]

Intenté utilizar este código sin embargo es obvio que la igualdad en el left join no es correcta

Query con Left Join

```
SELECT 
T01."Entry No_" AS "Nº mov.",
T01."G_L Account No_" AS "Nº cuenta",
T02."Name " AS "NCuenta",
T01."Posting Date" AS "Fecha registro",
T01."Document Type" AS "Tipo documento",
T01."Document No_" AS "Nº documento",
T01."Description" AS "Descripción",
T01."Amount" AS "Importe",
T01."Bal_ Account No_" AS "Cta. contrapartida",
T01."Global Dimension 2 Code" AS "Ddepto",
T03."Creation Date" AS "Fecha registro"
 FROM 
 RTM1.dbo."Empresa1 SA de CV$G_L Entry" "T01",
 RTM1.dbo."Empresa1 SA de CV$G_L Account" "T02"
 left join
 RTM1.dbo."Empresa1 SA de CV$G_L Register"  "T03"
 on 
T01."Entry No_" <=  "T03"."From Entry No_" 

 WHERE 
T01."G_L Account No_" = "T02".No_
 AND  "T01"."Posting Date" BETWEEN '16/06/2022 00:00:00' AND '16/06/2022 00:00:00'
 AND  "T01"."G_L Account No_" like '11%'
 And T01."Reversed" = 0
```

---

No se puede aplicar igualdad en left join porque al ser guardados los movimientos por rangos algunos se perderían

Comment: EN qué base de datos es esto? Por favor ve a [edit] y añade esta info. Suelen usarse las etiquetas para esto

Comment: ¿Por alguna razón estás haciendo esto `T01."Entry No_" <=  "T03"."From Entry No_" `? ¿No debería ser `T01."Entry No_" =  "T03"."From Entry No_"`?